# How can I set that when user is admin only then he can view a specific html page in Django

Tags: django

I've a html page called **admin_dashboard.html**. So, there is a button in the navbar called **Admin Dashboard** only admin can get this button. If admin click this button he will go to the **admin_dashboard.html** but a staff can also go to that page by using urls which is **http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin_dashboard**. So I want that a if staff manually types this url and tries to go to the **admin_dashboard.html** it will throw an error.

here is my code for that button

```
            {%if user.is_superuser%}
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="admin_dashboard">Admin Dashboard</i></a></li>
            {%endif%}
```

**urls.py:**

```
   path("admin_dashboard", views.admin_dashboard, name='admin_dashboard')
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def admin_dashboard(request):
    return render(request,'admin_dashboard.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def admin_dashboard(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser :  
      return render(request,'admin_dashboard.html')
    else: 
        return render(request,'html_view_with_error',{"error" : "PERMISSION DENIED"})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if it is `superuser` or not in `views.py` and render `template` accordingly as

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def admin_dashboard(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser == True:
        return render(request, 'admin_dashboard.html')
    else:
        # render to any html if it is not `superuser`
        return render(request, 'non_superuser_dashboard.html')
```